# References on the structure of bond percolation on the (finite) 2D-grid in the sub-critical regime (e.g p=1/10)

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, random-graphs, percolation

Would appreciate references to the most up-to-date results for the structure of bond percolation on the (finite) 2D-grid in the sub-critical regime (e.g, $p=1/10$).
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is a place to start, from which to search forward in time:

> Grimmett, Geoffrey. *Percolation*. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg, 1999.
>   ([Springer link](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540649021).)

---

[image: Perc]

          

<sup>(Image from Massimo Franceshetti.)</sup>

---

Comment: This (the image) looks like site percolation, but the reference is still relevant.

Comment: @Bach: Good point. To quote D. Genin: "Every bond percolation problem can be realized as a site percolation problem (on a different
graph)."